# Convert Visual Studio 2017 C# solution / project for use with Mono on Linux?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core, mono

I have a normal C# windows x64 console application project contained within a Visual Studio 2017 solution.  It compiles on windows in Visual Studio.  It is targeting .NET v4.7.1, although, I believe it would compile on lower .NET versions.

I want to port the application to run on Linux using Mono.  What is the procedure to do this?

I have tried simply running `dotnet build` but this gives error messages:

```
user@user-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/svm_compute/svm_compute$ dotnet build
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.0.450+ga8dc7f1d34 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Nothing to do. None of the projects specified contain packages to restore.
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.203/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(775,5): error : The OutputPath property is not set for project 'svm_compute.csproj'.  Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this project.  Configuration='Debug'  Platform='AnyCPU'.  You may be seeing this message because you are trying to build a project without a solution file, and have specified a non-default Configuration or Platform that doesn't exist for this project. [/home/user/Desktop/svm_compute/svm_compute/svm_compute.csproj]

Build FAILED.
```

Then, I tried `dotnet build svm_compute.csproj /p:ConfigurationPlatforms=Release /p:Platform="x64"`, which also gave errors:

```
user@user-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/svm_compute/svm_compute$ dotnet build svm_compute.csproj /p:ConfigurationPlatforms=Release /p:Platform="x64"
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.0.450+ga8dc7f1d34 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Nothing to do. None of the projects specified contain packages to restore.
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.203/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1183,5): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend. [/home/user/Desktop/svm_compute/svm_compute/svm_compute.csproj]

Build FAILED.
```

On the other hand, if I use the IDE `monodevelop` I am able to load the solution, build it and run it.  However, that isn't very useful, since I need to be able to build it and run it through the linux command line interface without using an IDE...

Comment: MSB3644... no ref assembies found, common problem on linux... setting an env. var.  
 for `FrameworkPathOverride` to the proper mono lib... ( i.e. /lib/mono/5.xxx ) will solve that. Also using `msbuild` instead of `dotnet` (which in turn is using msbuild) might solve your problem directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the target your project is `.Net Framework`, the build tool you should use is `msbuild` (included in the recent version of mono, please refer to https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/ and install `mono-devel` package for your linux.

open a terminal window, navigate to the directory of your project, and try to build it with `msbuild /t:build`, and if you have references to nuget, please try `msbuild /t:restore` first.

the `dotnet` command is only used for `.Net Core` projects.